# Why does the first category returned get echoed twice?

Tags: children, categories, get-children

I have a category called menu items (category id 19) and two child categories Tacos and Burgers. Why does Tacos get echoed out twice? I get Tacos Tacos Burgers.

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
        if (cat_is_ancestor_of(19, $childcat)) {
            echo $childcat->cat_name;
        } 
    }
endwhile;
```

Comment: it assumes you have 2 posts having "tacos" category and 1 post with "burgers" category assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are echoing the `$childcat->cat_name` each time a post passes the validation.

Remember that you are inside the loop and for each post that matches your condition your are echoing. You seem to be wanting to print a list of categories that are a child of `19` but I don't see why you'd go over each post to do that.

I would give you a solution but I'm not sure where you are going with this, if you share what you are trying to accomplish I will update my answer